# cleartool support on Ubuntu without using rich client

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-remote-client

Is there a way to get native clear case support on Ubuntu 12+? I've only seen it supported via remote rich client. We have red hat and suse machines with cleartool installed and I would like a similar set up for Ubuntu so we could re-use the same scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The "[System Requirements for Rational ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036569)" from IBM does mention Ubuntu, but with the caveat:

### Ubuntu 12.04 kernel issue with ClearCase 8.0.1:

> For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, do not use Kernel 3.5. This kernel is not a LTS and is not supported by ClearCase. Even though Ubuntu will try to upgrade the kernel to 3.5, **you must keep using kernel 3.2.x to be able to use ClearCase**.